# problem minus in mysql in subtratcting group data

Tags: mysql, database

i have three table
member (**memberid**,m_name,statusid,address,DOB,phone)
booking (**bookingid**, memberid ,sessionid, cost)
session(**sessionid**, activity,location)

(fk memberid, fk sessionid )BOOKING IS link with ( member pk )and (session pk)

session activity  is like football,swimming,badminton,tennis
i want to run the following query

### find the name of all member who have booked any session for 'football', but not any session for 'swimming' during december 2009

sql

```
 select DISTINCT  Event1.m_name ,Event1.activity
       FROM
       (
            select mm.m_name,ss.activity,ss.sessionid,ss.s_date
                 from member mm
                 inner join booking bb on bb.memberid = mm.memberid
                 inner join session ss   on ss.sessionid = bb.sessionid
                where activity = 'football'
       )as Event1

INNER JOIN
    (
         select mm.m_name ,ss.activity,ss.sessionid,ss.s_date
               from member mm
               inner join booking bb on bb.memberid = mm.memberid
               inner join session ss  on ss.sessionid = bb.sessionid
               where mm.memberid not in
                   (
                    select mm.memberid
                    from member mm
                     inner join booking bb
                     on bb.bookingid = mm.memberid
                     inner join session ss
                     on bb.sessionid = ss.sessionid
                     where ss.activity in ( 'swimming')
             )

     ) as Event2

on Event1.sessionid = Event2.sessionid
```

what im doing wrong it return me memeber who have book football and swmming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT m_name
FROM members
WHERE memberid IN
  ( SELECT b.memberid
    FROM booking b
      JOIN session s
        ON s.sessionid = b.sessionid
    WHERE s.activity = "football"
  )
AND memberid NOT IN
  ( SELECT b.memberid
    FROM booking b
      JOIN session s
        ON s.sessionid = b.sessionid
    WHERE s.activity = "swimming"
  )
```

or

```
SELECT m.m_name
FROM members m
WHERE EXISTS
  ( SELECT 0
    FROM booking b
      JOIN session s
        ON s.sessionid = b.sessionid
    WHERE s.activity = "football"
      AND b.memberid = m.memberid
  )
AND NOT EXISTS
  ( SELECT 0
    FROM booking b
      JOIN session s
        ON s.sessionid = b.sessionid
    WHERE s.activity = "swimming"
      AND b.memberid = m.memberid
  )
```

or

```
SELECT m.m_name
FROM booking b 
  JOIN members m
    ON m.memberid = b.memberid
  JOIN session s
    ON s.sessionid = b.sessionid
WHERE s.activity IN ("football", "swimming")
GROUP BY b.memberid
HAVING COUNT(s.activity = "swimming") = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
m_name,
(
    SELECT COUNT(bookingid)
    FROM booking
    WHERE memberid = ROOT.memberid
    AND sessionid = [session.sessionid for football]
) AS FootballSessions,
(
    SELECT COUNT(bookingid)
    FROM booking
    WHERE memberid = ROOT.memberid
    AND sessionid = [session.sessionid for swimming]
) AS SwimmingSessions
FROM member ROOT
HAVING FootballSessions > 0
AND SwimmingSessions = 0
```

You may need to say `WHERE` instead of `HAVING` near the end there, but that should work.

Answer (score 0):

This looks suspect :

inner join booking bb on *bb.bookingid = mm.memberid*